# Why does this code for processing many CSV files get slow as it keeps running?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have around 5000 CSV files which I have to open one by one, do some processing and close it.

For this instead of using multiprocessing code, I tried to replicate it using the `open` function. So I can run this python script multiple times to take the advantage of multiprocessing in a way.

If I run the code lets say 5 times, in the beginning the files are saved very fast as 5 codes are running but as the time goes on, after around 50-60% of the files are processed, the complete process becomes very slow. Then it seems like running one code is even faster than 5 codes running simultaneously.

What can be the reason behind this?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime, time

files = os.listdir('E:\\Data\\stocks')

for i in files:
    if i in os.listdir('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\'):
        continue
    d = open('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\' + i, 'a+')
    d.close()
    df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Data\\stocks\\' + i)
    df.rename(columns={'Datetime': 'Date_time'}, inplace=True)
    df['Date_time'] = df['Date_time'].str.split('+').str[0]
    df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df['Date'] = df['Date_time'].dt.date
    df['Time'] = df['Date_time'].dt.time 
    df.to_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\' + i, index=False)

    print(i)
```

Comment: It sounds like saturating IO - a hard drive or an SSD can only do a limited number of operations per second. In case of HDD, reading from different tracks in parallel (as opposed to long sequential reads) is especially detrimental to performance

Comment: Also, as you create new files in the destination folder, the `if i in os.listdir(...` will become slower. Perhaps you could preprocess the source files first?

Comment: @Marat I am using SSD. Yes limited number of operations per second is correct, but why it gets slower than. Shouldn't it be running at a constant speed throughout ?

Comment: You can memorize the files you already handled in a set `'E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\' + i` - no need to call `os.listdir`

Comment: @quamrana Sorry, what do you mean by preprocessing the source files first ?

Comment: In general, I think that what you get from using `pandas` is very little and can be easily solved without it. BTW  what is `len(files)` ?

Comment: @balderman If i don't call os.listdir in a loop, then I won't be able to run multiple codes at once since it will help in identifying which files are already done and therefore those files won't be processed again

Comment: @Anilkumar - do you run this code in parallel? As I said - keep the file names in a set (`handled_files = set()`) and check if a file is in this set

Comment: Yes, I will run this code multiple times to fasten up the process

Comment: Will few copies run in parallel? If the answer is yes do the following. Use multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) .Each process will get a subset of the files and will work on his private subset. With this you no longer need to call `os.listdir`

Comment: as others mentioned, definitely **avoid** calling `os.listdir` in loop. I would expect that slow down your code by itself, especially if directory has thousands of files as mentioned, and if you're adding files to tha tdirectory. instead create a new set and add processed filenames on each loop iteration. then check if that file is in that set so you don't need to process it again.

Comment: also, a bit off topic I find the below to be an interesting read. You can save a lot on I/O by using a different format than csv.

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

Answer (score 1):

You need to go with something like the below

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import os


def handle_csv(file_name):
    # TODO - implement
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p: # TODO change 5 which is the number of processes
        files_to_handle = os.listdir('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\')
        print(p.map(handle_csv, files_to_handle))
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Rough re-implementation of your function but with much better performance

```py
from typing import List
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
import time

from pandas import DataFrame

files = os.listdir('E:\\Data\\stocks')


async def process_file(_df):
    _df.rename(columns={'Datetime': 'Date_time'}, inplace=True)
    _df['Date_time'] = _df['Date_time'].str.split('+').str[0]
    _df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(_df['Date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    _df['Date'] = _df['Date_time'].dt.date
    _df['Time'] = _df['Date_time'].dt.time
    return _df


async def _is_valid(_file) -> bool:
    """checks if file can be opened meaning its a valid file """
    async with aiofiles.open(_file, mode='r') as f:
        # noinspection PyBroadException
        try:
            if await f.read():
                return True
        except Exception:
            return False


async def read_and_process(_files: []) -> List[str]:
    """not completely asynchronous but much better than before"""

    # creating a list comprehension of existing files to avoid having to check multiple times within the loop
    _valid_files: List[str] = [file for file in files if await _is_valid(file)]

    for _file in _valid_files:
        processed_file = await process_file(pd.read_csv('E:\\Data\\stocks\\' + _file))
        await processed_file.to_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\' + _file, index=False)
    # returning the list of processed files so we can print the filenames once we are done rather than printing
    # a file at a time -- IO Operations on a loop - slows down execution unless they can be done asynchronously
    return _valid_files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = asyncio.run(read_and_process(_files=files))
    # NOTE: Printing the list once done increases the speed also
    print(*files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pre-process the files first to reduce the `O(n^2)` effect of testing each successive file against an increasing number of files in the target folder:

```py
targets = os.listdir('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Zerodha another\\')
files = [i for i in os.listdir('E:\\Data\\stocks') if i not in targets]

for i in files:
    ...
```

In the above code, `files` becomes a list based on the files in the source folder that are not already present in the target folder. The target folder is just scanned once for all its filenames.